# Using my Helper(Razor syntax) inside a JQuery-template?

Tags: razor, jquery-templates

Is there anyway to use Razor inside of JQuery template!?!?

```
<td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
            </button>
**@Html.LookupValues("Hrm_PeriodStatus_PeriodStatusType",CalendarPeriodFields.PeriodStatusType, "V_PeriodStatusTypeTitle")**   
        {% } %}</td>
     {% } else { %}
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    {% } %}
    <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
        <button class="btn btn-warning">
            <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
        </button>
    {% } %}</td>
```

I want to create a dropdown inside this template but the proccess is completely separate!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use server side helpers inside a static file such as javascript unless this javascript file is rendered through a server side handler.

For example you could have a controller action which is serving a view:

```
public class MyTemplatesController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
        return View();
    }
}
```

and then you could have a corresponding view which will contain your template (`~/Views/MyTemplates/Index.cshtml`) and in which you could use server side helpers:

```
<td class="start">
    {% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
        <button class="btn btn-primary">
            <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
            <span>{%=locale.fileupload.start%}</span>
        </button>
        @Html.LookupValues(
            "Hrm_PeriodStatus_PeriodStatusType",
            CalendarPeriodFields.PeriodStatusType, 
            "V_PeriodStatusTypeTitle"
        )
    {% } %}
</td>
{% } else { %}
    <td colspan="2"></td>
{% } %}
<td class="cancel">
{% if (!i) { %}
   <button class="btn btn-warning">
       <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
       <span>{%=locale.fileupload.cancel%}</span>
   </button>
{% } %}
</td>
```

and then you could reference this script:

```
<script id="someTemplate" src="@Url.Action("MyTemplates", "Index")" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl"></script>
```

Comment: Clever way!!
logically your idea must work.
but don`t know why, your solution didn`t work!!
the script came correctly but nothing happend!